# Magento 2 Add Image To cart API response object

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, api, rest-api

Magento 2 how to add image url for the rest api's called **V1/carts/mine** & **V1/carts/cartId**

Please find the below screenshots.

[image]

[image]
Please suggest me thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create extension attributes in extension_attributes.xml file like below.

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface">
        <attribute code="image_url" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
```

Add one observer for event "sales_quote_load_after" in observer add below code.

```
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterfaceFactory as ProductRepository;
    use Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory as ProductImageHelper;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface as StoreManager;
    use Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation as AppEmulation;
    use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemExtensionFactory;

    class SalesQuoteLoadAfter implements ObserverInterface
    {   
        /**
         * @var ObjectManagerInterface
         */
        protected $_objectManager;

        /**
         * @var ProductRepository
         */
        protected $productRepository;

        /**
         *@var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
         */
        protected $productImageHelper;

        /**
         *@var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $storeManager;

        /**
         *@var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
         */
        protected $appEmulation;

        /**
         * @var CartItemExtensionFactory
         */
        protected $extensionFactory;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
         * @param ProductRepository $productRepository
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\ImageFactory
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation
         * @param CartItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            ProductRepository $productRepository,
            ProductImageHelper $productImageHelper,
            StoreManager $storeManager,
            AppEmulation $appEmulation,
            CartItemExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
        ) {
            $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
            $this->productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
            $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->appEmulation = $appEmulation;
            $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
        }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $quote = $observer->getQuote();

           /**
             * Code to add the items attribute to extension_attributes
             */
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
                $product = $this->productRepository->create()->getById($quoteItem->getProductId());
                $itemExtAttr = $quoteItem->getExtensionAttributes();
                if ($itemExtAttr === null) {
                    $itemExtAttr = $this->extensionFactory->create();
                }
                $imageurl = $this->getImageUrl($product, 'product_thumbnail_image');
                $itemExtAttr->setImageUrl($imageurl);
                $quoteItem->setExtensionAttributes($itemExtAttr);
            }
            return;
        }

        /**
         * Helper function that provides full cache image url
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
         * @return string
         */
        protected function getImageUrl($product, string $imageType = '')
        {
            $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

            $this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId, \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
            $imageUrl = $imageUrl = $this->productImageHelper->create()->init($product, $imageType)->getUrl();

            $this->appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();

            return $imageUrl;
        }
    }
```

You will able to see response something like below

```
"items": [
        {
            "item_id": 215,
            "sku": "simple",
            "qty": 2,
            "name": "Simple product",
            "price": 840,
            "product_type": "simple",
            "quote_id": "184",
            "extension_attributes": {
                "image_url": "http://local.magento.com/media/catalog/product/cache/image/25x25/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/c/4/c4.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: hi @manish i am getting an error http://prntscr.com/g96i11

Comment: I have updated my answer with the "use" statements I used above the class.

Comment: $this->itemExtensionFactory doesn't exist?

Comment: now i am able to compile the code  but please confirm the next step whether i have to check the output in the postmen ?

Comment: Yes. You have to check the output in postman or any other client. Use the GET request to fetch the cart details. In cart items extension attributes you will able to see the result.

Comment: thanks but one small error that is $this->itemExtensionFactory->create() undefined?

Comment: i am getting an error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method setImageUrl()

Comment: Please run the setup:di:compile command and flush the cache.
Have you added the attribute in /etc/extension_attributes.xml file?

Comment: Your getters and setter should have get created in var/generation/Magento/Quote/Api/Data/CartItemExtension.php.
And sorry I have updated my answer for again. Changed the last line of use statement from OrderItemExtensionFactory to CartItemExtensionFactory.

Comment: thanks for reply @manish i am checking now i will get back to u

Comment: Hi manish please  check this link what i have followed the steps https://github.com/NagarajuKasa/demo/blob/master/Extensionattributes.txt

Comment: We need to implement the same for orders api as well. Mark the correct answer when you are done with this.

Comment: Hi manish i got the output thank you very much for your lovely support one small corrections i.e change the extension_attributes.xml => keep Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterface

Comment: I have updating the answer my github link you can check the same if you need, once again thanks for your help and support.

Comment: Thanks @manish_khot and Nagaraju, it worked for me as well. I am trying to use it  for order items as well.

Comment: oh good, glad to hear @mshakeel happy coding and all the best